# How to show debug info overlay screen?

Tags: android

In Developer Options we can enable show cpu usage. And it will show overlay info.
I need to show some debug info in app overlay screen like shown cpu usage. How to do it? May be i can use some library for it?

Answer (score 0):

One approach would be to use`DialogFragment` with following

```
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    Window window = getDialog().getWindow();
    window.requestFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    window.clearFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_DIM_BEHIND);
    window.setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_NOT_TOUCH_MODAL);
    window.setBackgroundDrawableResource(R.color.some_color_with_say_50%_alpha_value);
```